# from tkinter.ttk import * interfering with check box list

Tags: python, python-3.x, checkbox, tkinter, text-files

I have imported `from tkinter.ttk import *` so my drop down menu works correctly, with this module the drop down menu doesn't duplicate some of the choices and makes the window the width of the text inside.

However with the module by check box window doesn't work and displays nothing other than a blank window.
What can I do so both work correctly.

Code for drop down:

```
import random
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *

with open('Comedy films', encoding='latin-1') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    value_fifteen_one=(random.choice(lines))
    value_fifteen_two=(random.choice(lines))
    value_fifteen_three=(random.choice(lines))
    value_fifteen_four=(random.choice(lines))
    value_fifteen_five=(random.choice(lines))

def menu_fifteen():      
    root15 = Tk()
    root15.title("Film choices")

    menu = Frame(root15)
    menu.pack(pady = 5, padx = 50)          
    var = StringVar(root15)

    options = [
            value_fifteen_one,
            value_fifteen_two,
            value_fifteen_three,
            value_fifteen_four,
            value_fifteen_five,
    ]
    option = OptionMenu(menu, var, options[0], *options, command=functionsfifteen)
    var.set('Select')
    option.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

    root15.mainloop()


def functionsfifteen(value):
    if value == value_fifteen_one:            
        print("Playing "+value_fifteen_one)
    if value == value_fifteen_two:            
        print("Playing "+value_fifteen_two)
    if value == value_fifteen_three:            
        print("Playing "+value_fifteen_three)
    if value == value_fifteen_four:            
        print("Playing "+value_fifteen_four)
    if value == value_fifteen_five:            
        print("Playing "+value_fifteen_five)
```

Code for check box:

```
def interests():
    check = Tk()
    check.title("Interests")

    CheckVar1 = BooleanVar()
    CheckVar2 = BooleanVar()
    CheckVar3 = BooleanVar()
    CheckVar4 = BooleanVar()


    C1 = Checkbutton(check, text = "Horror", variable = CheckVar1, \
                     onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, height=1, \
                     width = 20)
    C2 = Checkbutton(check, text = "Action", variable = CheckVar2, \
                     onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, height=1, \
                     width = 20)
    C3 = Checkbutton(check, text = "Science fiction", variable = CheckVar3, \
                     onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, height=1, \
                     width = 20)
    C4 = Checkbutton(check, text = "Comedy", variable = CheckVar4, \
                     onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, height=1, \
                     width = 20)

    def submitHandle():
        anyChecked = CheckVar1.get() | CheckVar2.get() | CheckVar3.get(
        ) | CheckVar4.get()
        if anyChecked:
            check.destroy()
        else:
            messagebox.showerror("Error", "Please check at least one.")

    submit_btn = Button(check, text="Submit", command=lambda: submitHandle()) #Submit button on the check button menu window


    C1.pack()
    C2.pack()
    C3.pack()
    C4.pack()
    submit_btn.pack()
    check.mainloop()


    if CheckVar1.get():
        filename = ("Horror");
        with open (filename, "a") as f:
            f.write("")

    if CheckVar2.get():
        filename = ("Action");
        with open (filename, "a") as f:
            f.write("")

    if CheckVar3.get():
        filename = ("Science fiction");
        with open (filename, "a") as f:
            f.write("")

    if CheckVar4.get():
        filename = ("Comedy");
        with open (filename, "a") as f:
            f.write("")
```

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly why you shouldn't do wildcard imports, especially with tkinter and ttk. They both export objects with the same name.

The best solution is to change your imports, and then change your code to match.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
...
root15 = tk.Tk()
...
```

Comment: Thanks, quick question - what would I define menu as, because Frame is not defined due to not being part of any imports.